# How can I convert char* to long string to use it in FindFirstFile funtion?

Tags: c++, winapi

I set the char* array for the search directory so the user can type in where to look for files and the FindFirstFile function should use it. I already found out that if you set the search directory in code you just add "L" before the "text" to convert it. But how to make it convert regular string to long string? It says that it needs LPCWSTR as an input but if I just try to convert it with (LPCWSTR) it's not finding any files. Yet I also may do something wrong in handling the array itself as I'm a noobie at coding and make those mistakes some times

Also I know about those different structures for string in C yet I'm not allowed yo use anything of object-oriented programming in this project so I have to stick with this

```
struct drtctrAr
{
    char* str = NULL;
}; 

int main()
{
    system("chcp 1251");

    char tmpstr[1000];
    drtctrAr drctr;
    int len;
    
    printf("Please enter the directory: ");
    gets_s(tmpstr, 1000);

    len = strlen(tmpstr)+1;
    drctr.str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
    strcpy_s(drctr.str, len, tmpstr);

    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hf;

    hf = FindFirstFile((LPCWSTR)&drctr.str, &FindFileData);
    if (hf == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Error opening files or no files found!");
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            printf("Found file: %ls", FindFileData.cFileName);
            printf("\n");
        } while (FindNextFile(hf, &FindFileData) != 0);
        FindClose(hf);
    }

    free(drctr.str);
```

Comment: Why not use `wchar_t*` as input, instead of `char*`? You can also use `FindFirstFileA` for the ascii equivalent function.

Comment: I'm just very unfamiliar with wchar and the aspects of working with it.

Comment: Same way you work with `char`  it's just a wide character.

Comment: How to write the LPWIN32_FIND_DATAA then? The ascii version requires it instead of mine

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `wchar_t*` instead of `char*`

Your struct would change to:

```
struct drtctrAr
{
    wchar_t* str = NULL;
};
```

Your `tmpStr` would also change:

```
wchar_t tmpstr[1000];
    
printf("Please enter the directory: ");
_getws_s(tmpstr, 1000);

len = wcslen(tmpstr)+1;
drctr.str = (wchar_t*)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * len);
wcscpy_s(drctr.str, len, tmpstr);
```

---

Alternatively, winapi functions like `FindFirstFile` are actually just a MACRO which calls defines it as either `FindFirstFileW` or `FindFirstFileA`. You can explicitly use the `A` version to use the ASCII version. Same goes for `FindNextFileA` and `WIN32_FIND_DATAA`

Comment: The ascii version requires LPWIN32_FIND_DATAA instead of WIN32_FIND_DATA yet simply changing it in code does not help  and I can't understand what to change in HANDLE

Comment: `LPWIN32_FIND_DATAA` is a pointer to a `WIN32_FIND_DATAA` structure. You already have `&FindFileData` which would get the address to the structure (a pointer)

Comment: But it say in function error message "argument of type `LPWIN32_FIND_DATAA *`" is incompatible with parameter of type `LPWIN32_FIND_DATAA`" if I leave the `&FindFileData`

Comment: Did you change `FindFileData;` to `WIN32_FIND_DATAA FindFileData;`? or did you change its type to `LP...`?

Comment: To `LP`... Just got what it means, lemme try

Comment: Yet still no idea how to convert my array to something the FindFirstFile function will eat

Comment: `FindFirstFileA` will work fine for `char*`. If you require `FindFirstFile` (using the `W` version), then you can use the rest of the code I supplied which uses `wchar_t*` instead of `char*`. There is no reason here to convert from `char*` to `wchar_t*` (which is `LPWSTR`)

Comment: Oooooh, that's the difference! Thanks for the explanation! Also there was no need to use `&` as I finally understood

Answer (score 1):

You are compiling your program with `UNICODE` enabled.  You are calling the TCHAR version of the Win32 API functions, which are mapping to the Unicode version, which is why the functions are expecting `LPCWSTR` (`const wchar_t*`) strings.

If you need to use `char` strings, use the ANSI version of the Win32 API functions instead, eg;

```cpp
struct drtctrAr
{
    char* str = NULL;
}; 

int main()
{
    system("chcp 1251");

    char tmpstr[1000];
    drtctrAr drctr;
    int len;
    
    printf("Please enter the directory: ");
    gets_s(tmpstr, 1000);

    len = strlen(tmpstr)+1;
    drctr.str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
    strcpy_s(drctr.str, len, tmpstr);

    WIN32_FIND_DATAA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hf;

    hf = FindFirstFileA(drctr.str, &FindFileData);
    if (hf == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Error opening files or no files found!");
        free(drctr.str); 
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            printf("Found file: %s\n", FindFileData.cFileName);
        } while (FindNextFileA(hf, &FindFileData));
        FindClose(hf);
    }

    free(drctr.str);
```

Otherwise, change your code to use `wchar_t` strings instead:

```cpp
struct drtctrAr
{
    wchar_t* str = NULL;
}; 

int main()
{
    system("chcp 1251");

    wchar_t tmpstr[1000];
    drtctrAr drctr;
    int len;
    
    printf("Please enter the directory: ");
    _getws_s(tmpstr, 1000);

    len = lstrlenW(tmpstr)+1;
    drctr.str = (wchar_t*)malloc(sizeof(wchar_t) * len);
    wcscpy_s(drctr.str, len, tmpstr);

    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    HANDLE hf;

    hf = FindFirstFileW(drctr.str, &FindFileData);
    if (hf == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Error opening files or no files found!");
        free(drctr.str);
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            wprintf(L"Found file: %s\n", FindFileData.cFileName);
        } while (FindNextFileW(hf, &FindFileData));
        FindClose(hf);
    }

    free(drctr.str);
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use `FindFirstFile` which is `FindFirstFileW` by default, it takes wide char (`LPCWSTR`) as an input, so you need to make input `wchar_t*`. Yet you can stick with regular `char*` but then you need to modify `FindFirstFile` function to use specifically ascii version which is `FindFirstFileA` and also modify `WIN32_FIND_DATA` which is used for `FindFirstFileW` to `WIN32_FIND_DATAA`, the ascii version

Comment: You really don't want to be using the ANSI API. Use Unicode.